# Set start_time to end_time if blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am working on an Events Model with start datetime & end datetime. It should fill in the start datetime as the end datetime if start is blank, as stated in the test. I set up validations to require start/end presence to be true but this is obviously not what the test is asking for as it fails. I am pretty new to this and not familiar with creating/fixing tests so the answer may be right in front of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds as if you need a `before_save` callback.

```rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :ensure_start_time

  def ensure_start_time
    start_time ||= end_time
    # i.e. set start_time = end_time if start_time is nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped! I was also filtering the events to only show upcoming events by start_time. This has made it to where events whose start_time are filled in with the end_time do not show. This is what I have in the index action..  @events = Event.where('start_time >= ?', Date.today).order(:start_time)